# multidimensional array into one-dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I convert this array form:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 ) 
[1] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 ) [2] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 )
[3] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 ) [4] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 ) 
[5] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 ) [6] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 ) 
[7] => Array ( [quantity] => 200.00000000 ) )
```

to this form:

```
 Array ( [0] => 200 [1] => 200 [2] => 200 [3] => 200 [4] => 200 [6] => 200 [7] => 200 )
```

in PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$result = array_map('current', $array);`

Comment: @deceze That should definitely be an answer, either with `'current'` or `'reset'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function may help you

```
function convert($array)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
        $result[] = $value['quantity'];
    return $result;
}

$array = convert($array);
```